# Редактирование реестра пользователя в \HKEY_USERS\<SID пользователя>\. Загрузка куста пользователя

Tags: c#, windows, реестр

Необходимо изменить/прочитать/добавить переменную Shell в реестре Windows по пути \HKEY_USERS\\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon для каждого пользователя. Однако в \HKEY_USERS\ находятся только пользователи, у которых выполнен вход. Если я правильно понял из статей в интернете, то нужно загружать кусты пользователей в реестр, хранящиеся в C:\Users\<Имя пользователя>\NTUSER.DAT, что я и попытался сделать:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern Int32 RegLoadKey(UInt32 hKey, String lpSubKey, String lpFile);

public enum HKEY : uint
{
        LOCAL_MACHINE = 0x80000002,
        USERS = 0x80000003
}


static void LoadUserHive()
{
    string path = "C:\\Users\\Max\\NTUSER.DAT";
    string SID = "S-1-5-21-2185061059-2250993091-2609513880-1001";
    RegLoadKey((uint)HKEY.USERS, SID, path);
}
```

Код выполняется без ошибок, но куста пользователя в \HKEY_USERS\ не наблюдается.

Подскажите, что я делаю не так

Comment: что такое `куст пользователя`?

Comment: *Подскажите, что я делаю не так* Вручную делаете то, для чего есть автоматизированные инструменты. Создайте в планировщике задание на создание этого ключа при логоне любого пользователя - безусловном или только при отсутствии. *Если я правильно понял из статей в интернете, то нужно загружать кусты пользователей в реестр, хранящиеся в C:\Users\<Имя пользователя>\NTUSER.DAT, что я и попытался сделать* Ага... не проверив, есть ли права, является ли этот профиль профилем интерактивного пользователя, не отключен ли он, и т.п...

Comment: @tym32167 Куст реестра - это группа разделов, подразделов и параметров реестра с набором вспомогательных файлов, содержащих резервные копии этих данных. https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/256986/windows-registry-information-for-advanced-users

Comment: Прикольно, спасибо. Первый раз слышу такой термин :)

Comment: @Akina В программе это проверяется. Конкретно с пользователем `Max` из вопроса все хорошо, он включен и интерактивным не является. Что касается варианта с Планировщиком задач, то он не подойдет, так как помимо записи, программе необходимо также и счиать эту переменную [Shell по пути \HKEY_USERS\\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon] (извеняюсь, забыл указать в вопросе)

Comment: Также буду рад услышать альтернативный способ замены рабочего стола (explorer.exe) у определенных пользователей

Comment: *как помимо записи, программе необходимо также и счиать эту переменную* По-моему, Вы пытаетесь одним телодвижением решить две несвязанные задачи. Записать, чтобы потом прочитать - чем не ерунда? али не знаешь, что записывал? Записать ДРУГОМУ пользователю, чтобы потом прочитать У НЕГО - вот нафига? всё равно от ЕГО имени - не запустится сейчас, а когда запустится - так планировщик уже отработал...

Comment: @Akina Хорошо, опишу ситуацию. Делаю альтернативный рабочий стол - вместо explorer.exe. В этой программе можно выбрать пользователей, которым необходимо установить ее как рабочий стол.
В этом окне должно отображаться у каких пользователей он уже установлен, а у каких - нет. Для этого считывается значение Shell у каждого пользователя. Если оно соответствует пути моей программы,
значит у пользователя установлен мой рабочий стол, в противном случае считать, что не установлен.

Comment: Хранить информацию о том, для какого пользователя рабочий стол установлен, а для какого - нет,
считаю не совсем правильным, т. к. если значение той переменной Shell, будет изменено после установки моего рабочего стола, то программа будет ошибочно полагать, что для пользователя будет установлен
мой рабочий стол.

Comment: *Делаю альтернативный рабочий стол ... должно отображаться у каких пользователей он уже установлен, а у каких - нет.* Думаю, это важная информация, которую стоит из комментария переместить в текст вопроса.

Comment: @Akina так, блин, у меня проблема заключается в том, что не работает, как должна работать одна конкретная строчка в коде. Причем здесь то, что делает вся программа, я не понимаю, как и не понимаю зачем ты предлагаешь мне выполнить поставленную задачу по-другому, вместо того, что бы решить обозначенную в вопросе проблему, которая заключается в том, что строка, не делает то, что должна делать. К слову, я уже нашел решение, сейчас напишу в ответ. В любом случае, спасибо за оказанное внимание

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае, `RegLoadKey()` в случае ошибки не выдает исключений. Функция `RegLoadKey()` возвращает ноль в случае удачи, либо код ошибки `int` определенный в Winerror.h (класс для расшифорвки кодов ошибок для C# можно взять отсюда http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants.WINERROR).

Помимо прав администратора, для выполнения функции также обязательны привилегии `SE_RESTORE_NAME` и `SE_BACKUP_NAME`. Процесс их установки описан для C++  здесь https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/SecAuthZ/enabling-and-disabling-privileges-in-c--. Не составит труда перевести код из данного примера в C#. Либо можно использовать уже готовый класс для C# https://pastebin.com/R5HxeHnm.